# Runtime Error when setting up a dataSource to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, datasource

So I have this controller:

```
class OneIncidentController: IncidentController {

var number = 1;

let incident = Incident.getInstance()
var psyhicalsDataSource : MultipleSelectionsTable<Psyhical>?


@IBOutlet weak var psyhicalAggressionTable: UITableView!
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    psyhicalsDataSource = MultipleSelectionsTable<Psyhical>(tableData: Incident.getInstance().psyhicals)
    psyhicalAggressionTable.dataSource = psyhicalsDataSource!

}
```

and then I have the dataSource which is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class MultipleSelectionsTable<T : AVObject> : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
var tableData : Array<T>?

init(tableData : Array<T>?) {
    self.tableData = tableData
    super.init()
}

public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
    if tableData != nil {
    return tableData!.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("multipleSelectCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MultipleSelectCell

        cell?.textLabel?.text = tableData![indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
    }

    deinit {
        println("Object was deinitialized")
    }
}
```

But at runtime I get:

```
2014-12-15 15:07:40.183 AVSystem[3891:60b] -[_TtC8AVSystem23MultipleSelectionsTable0000000017DDCC0C tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dd9e90
2014-12-15 15:07:40.193 AVSystem[3891:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtC8AVSystem23MultipleSelectionsTable0000000017DDCC0C tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17dd9e90'
```

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is crashing in Obj-C code and current Obj-C and generics don't get along well. I'd file a bug with Apple and figure a way to remove the generic parameter from your class.

Try something like this instead:

```
@objc protocol AVObject {

}

public class MultipleSelectionsTable : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var tableData : Array<AnyObject>!

    func getTableData<T: AVObject >() -> Array<T> {
        return (tableData as? [T])!
    }

    func setTableData<T: AVObject>(x: Array<T>) -> Void {
        tableData = x as [AnyObject]
    }

    ...
}
```

Of course, this is a bit more dangerous as you're relying on your callers to ensure they ask for the correct type, but at least it'll crash as soon as the caller makes an invalid request.

Comment: I can't since the super-class is NSObject and UITableViewDataSource is a protocol

Comment: Ah, right, I'm used to just handling this stuff in the Table View Controller itself. I'll update my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Does this code work with a non-generic version of the class (i.e. `public class MultipleSelectionsTable : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource`) There may potentially be an issue with using generic swift types with this delegate.

Comment: It does work with a non-generic class... So I can't use generics there ?

Comment: It looks like the assertion is failing in objective-c code and obj-c [isn't compatible with Swift generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). Also, it looks like subclasses of generic classes must also be generic, so it doesn't look like you could get around it that way either. Unfortunately, it looks like you're stuck here. I'd recommend reporting it as a bug to Apple and figuring out how to do this without a generic class. Maybe you could create a generic TableProvider class and have your delegate hold it as a member?

Comment: @QuadroQ I've updated with an alternative to a generic delegate type.